# Возможно ли программным путём получить логическое выражение по таблице истинности?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Например, есть две переменные X и Y. Каждая может принимать значения 0 или 1. Нужно вывести зависимость между значениями и ответами. Не вручную найти, а написать программу возможно?

| X | Y | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Это же простые логические операторы. В чём необходимость?

Comment: `написать программу возможно?` возможно. Но для начала выберите язык, на котором собираетесь писать.

Comment: Необходимость найти формулу, для большого количества переменных. Пусть будет язык Пайтон. Каким способом это можно сделать, подскажите

Comment: А вариант через единственный нейрон не прокатит? (был подобный пример когда он сам рассчитывал перевод км в мили или курсы валют)

Comment: Чем-то подобным Кнут занимался в 4 томе "Искусства программирования", раздел 7.1.2. Он там искал как проще всего вычислять разные функции. Скажу прямо - меня не хватило чтоб разобраться во всем этом, впрочем, особо и не интересовало. Но советую посмотеть и туда.

Answer (score 10):

Это задача восстановления логической формулы по таблице истинности, одна из задач математической логики (например, получение СДНФ или СКНФ - в данном случае без разницы какой конкретно, результат будет эквивалентный).

Про СДНФ, СКНФ см.: [Совершенная дизъюнктивная нормальная форма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0), [Совершенная конъюнктивная нормальная форма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Для получения СДНФ нужно:

1. Отобрать только строки таблицы истинности, где результат равен 1
2. Внутри каждой строки там где 1 - берем просто соответствующую букву, где 0 - отрицание этой буквы, потом все буквы объединяем конъюнкцией (логическим "и")
3. Все обработанные строки объединяем дизъюнкцией (логическим "или")

Для СКНФ - по сути все то же самое, только наоборот)

Пример получения текстовой формулы СДНФ:

```
def get_sdnf(table):
    result = []
    for inputs, row_result in table.items():
        if row_result:
            row = []
            for value, letter in zip(inputs, 'XYZIJK'):
                row.append(('' if value else 'not ') + letter)
            
            result.append('({})'.format(' and '.join(row)))
    
    return ' or '.join(result)


# Ключи словаря - входы, значения - выходы
table = {
    (0, 0): 0,
    (0, 1): 0,
    (1, 0): 1,
    (1, 1): 1
}

print(get_sdnf(table))
```

Вывод:

```
(X and not Y) or (X and Y)
```

Для вашей таблицы истинности выведет просто `(X and not Y)`

Скобки на самом деле не нужны, т.к. у `and` более высокий приоритет, чем у `or`, но для удобства восприятия оставлю.

---

СДНФ и СКНФ могут получиться избыточными (например, по таблице истинности обычного `or` получится СДНФ вида `(not X and Y) or (X and not Y) or (X and Y)`, или могут остаться переменные, от которых результат вообще никак не зависит), и следующим шагом может быть получение минимальной дизъюнктивной нормальной формы (МДНФ) или минимальной конъюнктивной нормальной формы (МКНФ). Это может потребоваться, например, для реализации таблицы истинности минимальным количеством электронных компонентов. Но в условии вашей задачи ничего про минимальность не говорится, поэтому формально хватит и просто СДНФ. Если интересно, можете почитать про минимизацию [методом Куайна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Answer (score 0):

Оставив в стороне вопрос о разумности выбранного подхода, ответ да, можно.

Если коротко - то строится нейросеть. Обучается "на большом количестве данных", потом используется. Только странное это занятие - для логической схемы строить нейросеть. Про качество (точность) решения - даже не говорю.

Вот тут объясняется подробнее: https://habr.com/ru/post/516572/